# How to change the directory in which MediaWiki is installed after upgrading a temporary directory?

Tags: database, mediawiki, directory, software, upgrade

I have a section in my website which uses MediaWiki. eg. `sitename.com/codewiki/`

It has been 3 years since I installed MediaWiki. Now i am getting errors so i wanted to upgrade to the latest version.

I created a temporary section like `sitename.com/tempwiki/` and installed the latest release. It requested to upgrade the database, I said "yes" and it upgraded the db. Everything is fine. Now I wanted to change tempwiki to the actual live section codewiki. I could see in the database the path is hard coded like `/root/.../sitename/tempwiki/uploads`.

I am looking for is to upgrade a live site or to update the database with the directory name.

suggestions needed.

Answer (score 2):

For what I undestood the /codewiki/ is still working with the old database, right? If so, back it up and do the upgrade process again on the live version. You already saw it's working in the /tempwiki/ so it should be fine.

By taking a look at Mediawiki's [Upgrade Documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading), they address the live upgrading issue this way:

> **Can my wiki stay online while it is upgrading?** Generally yes, however Git may temporarily (for a few seconds) break it.
>
> If you are upgrading between minor releases of MediaWiki, all you need
>   to do is update the source files.
>
> Note: the following assumes you have command line access. If you are
>   upgrading between major releases of MediaWiki, the preferred procedure
>   is as follows:
>
> 1. Unpack the new version of MediaWiki into a new directory
> 2. Prepare that new directory: copy your current LocalSettings.php from the old directory, copy any installed extensions and custom skins
>      (if any).
> 3. In the release notes for the new version, see if any changes need to be made to LocalSettings.php.
> 4. Place the database in read-only mode by inserting the following variable into LocalSettings.php in the old directory - users will see
>      this message if they attempt an edit during the upgrade process:
>      $wgReadOnly = 'Upgrading to MediaWiki 1.24.0';
> 5. Run the update script or the web updater in the new directory.
> 6. Copy the images from the images sub-directory from the old directory to the new directory.
> 7. Swap the old directory and the new directory.

Seems like LocalSettings.php holds the information you need to edit in order to make it work.